# HTTP Listener not getting external calls

Tags: c#, winforms, httplistener

I have this Windows form app that wants to receive some calls from some external source.

I did some example based on this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-5.0

Its almost the same thing, i just did it to run on another thread.

```
    private static Form1 form;
    public static Thread httpServer;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form = new Form1();
        form.Load += OnFormLoad;
        Application.Run(form);
    }
    private static void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        httpServer = CreateHttp();
    }
    private static Thread CreateHttp()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        string[] prefixes = new string[1];

        prefixes[0] = "http://+:3070/";

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }
        listener.Start();

        var listeningThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(param =>
                {

                    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

                    string url = request.RawUrl;
                    
                    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello World </BODY></HTML>";
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    output.Close();

                }, null);
            }
        });

        listeningThread.IsBackground = true;
        listeningThread.Start();

        return listeningThread;
    }
```

When I call from localhost:3070 or 127.0.0.1:3070 it works, but if i try from ipadress:3070 I only get timeouts.

I'm already included this "3070" ports in my firewall....I also tried turning off my entire firewall

Also checked if the listener is working with the command :

netstat -na | find "3070"

TCP    0.0.0.0:3070           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:3070              [::]:0                 LISTENING

And also checked if this url is reserved with the command:

"netsh http show urlacl"

```
URL reservada            : http://+:3070/
    Usuário: \Todos
        Escutar: Yes
        Delegar: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

Anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Which IP do you use, and from which machine and network do you try to connect? If it's through a router, you're going to need to configure NAT. Please read [ask] and include all relevant details.

Comment: I Included all the things I thought it was relevant, sorry if I missed something.

I'm trying to conect over internet from another network.

I'm using my IPV4 public IP adress.... 189.33.66.124

Comment: _"'m trying to conect over internet from another network"_ - then you need port forwarding.

Comment: Have you tried setting the proxy in Internet *Options > Connections > Lan Settings* to 127.0.0.1 and port = 3070? After doing that, all the HTTP addresses that you browse will go though your proxy server (your application which is listening to the port).

Comment: CodeCaster, Already have. Will try to check if it is working.

@RezaAghaei, doing that it worked as expected.....but only works because I'm in the same Machine that is running the server.

Comment: On other machine, have you used the IP of your proxy machine in proxy settings?

Comment: No, you don't need to set a proxy server @Reza.